# Interpreting Quantified Predicate Formulas

Tags: predicate-logic

Does $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ mean that $(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ is true for all truth assignments to $x$ or does it mean that  $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ can be true or false depending on the truth assignment to $x$?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should come with a domain for $x$.

With a domain for $x$, if this statement is true, it means "For every $x$ in the domain, if $P(x)$ is true, then $Q(x)$ is true; if $P(x)$ is false, then $Q(x)$ is false".

The statement is false $iff$ there exists $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true but $Q(x)$ is false.

Comment: I voted for this answer because it is brief and clear and mostly correct. However, the clause "if $P(x)$ is false, then $Q(x)$ is false" is wrong and should be omitted. If it were changed to "if $Q(x)$ is false, then $P(x)$ is false," then the clause would be correct but redundant. Oh, also: that *is* what the statement means--whether it's true or not.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas of *first-order* (or *predicate*) logic, like :

> $∀x(P(x)→Q(x))$

are interpeted **not** with truth assignments, but through an *interpretation* $\mathcal M$, made of :

> - a (not empty) set of objects, called the *domain* of the interpretation; call it $M$
> - a suitable *reference* for every *constant* of the language (if any)
> - an assignement to each *predicate* letter of the language of a *relation* on $M$ of the suitable *arity*; i.e. if the *predicate* letter $P$ (as in our example) is *monadic* (i.e.has only one argument: arity = $1$) then we assign to it a subset $P^M$ of M (it will be the set of objects of the domain for which $P$ holds); if $R$ is a binary relation (a predicate with arity = $2$) then we assign to it a sucset $R^M$ of $M \times M$; and so on.

Consider now the language of *arithmetic*, with an individual constant : $\overline 0$, a function symbol $S$ for the *successor* function and a binary relation : $<$ for *less than*.

We interpret it in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers*, with the obvious interpretation for the above symbols.

Consider now the formula :

> $\forall x(x = \overline 0)$.

Intuitively, we expect that it will be true in $\mathbb N$ if, substituting to the *individual* variable the name for an object in the domain $\mathbb N$, we obtain a true formula, and this will happen with **all** numbers, i.e. for every object in the domain.

Consider a formula $A(x)$ with only $x$ free; we call an *instance* of it a formula $A[t/x]$ obtained from $A(x)$ putting the *closed term* $t$ (i.e. a "name" of an object) in place of $x$.

Assume that we have a name for every *number* (for every object in $\mathbb N$); we use $\overline k$ as name for the number $k$.

Now it's done !

> > The formula $\forall x (x = \overline 0)$ is *true* in $\mathbb N$ **iff** every instance : $(x = \overline 0)[\overline k/x]$ is *true* in $\mathbb N$.

With $0$ as $k$, we have that $(x = \overline 0)[\overline 0/x]$ is simply : $\overline 0 = \overline 0$ wich is true.

But with $1$ as $k$, we have that $(x = \overline 0)[\overline 1/x]$ is : $\overline 1 = \overline 0$ wich is obviously false.

Thus, having found an *instance* of $x = \overline 0$ which is *false*, we may conclude that (as expected) :

> > $\forall x (x = \overline 0)$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$.

---

Now, what about

> $∀x(P(x)→Q(x))$ ?

First of all, we have to choose a *domain* $M$ for our interpretation $\mathcal M$.

Second, we have to assign to the predicate letters $P$ and $Q$ two subset of the domain $M$, $P^M$ and $Q^M$ respectively.

Having done this, we have that the above formula will be *true* in $\mathcal M$ iff for every $a \in M$, if $\overline a$ is the name of $a$, the formula $(P(x)→Q(x))[\overline a/x]$ is true in $\mathcal M$.

In other terms,

> > $∀x(P(x)→Q(x))$ is true in the interpretation $\mathcal M$ iff for every $a \in M$, $(P(\overline a)→Q(\overline a))$ is true in it.