# Predicate and Statement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I was confused on some problems involving predicate.

First, there are many different definitions of predicate, the one I learned is "a predicate in one variable is a mathematical sentence involving a "free variable parameter" which ranged over a well-defined domain of values." Why are there so many different definitions of predicate??

Also, my professor says that the following sentence is a statement,
for every x in the set of D, P(x). Where P(x) is a predicate of variable x.

We know that for a predicate to be a statement, we need to quantify all variables, however, in the above statement, we didn't know what set D is. I mean, If we do not know set D, why would the above statement be a statement?

Comment: `"Why are there so many different definitions of predicate"?` The one you've given is the only one I've seen. Do you have a source for others? `"We didn't know what set D is. I mean, If we do not know set D, why would the above statement be a statement?"` Supposedly $D$ is a non-specified constant and if it is so, then the formula is a statement. You seem to be using the term *statement* with two different meanings too, so watch out.

Comment: Isn't there something called predicate calculus? I am so confused....

Comment: You have to review at least the basic definitions of the language of [first order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) and its semantics (based on the notion of *domain* of interpretation) and then the abbreviation called [bounded quantifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier).

Answer (score 1):

When you are confused in this way you need to take a step back. In mathematics many words are used in different ways in different contexts. For instance, in one topology class I took, a "map" was defined to be a continuous function. Then later in a differential geometry class, "map" was the broad term and a "function" was defined as a map with co-domain $\mathbb{R}$.

This things aren't defined in this way to confuse you, English just only has so many synonyms and so words have to pull multiple duties sometimes.

You are correct that there is something called the predicate calculus, however it isn't really relevant here and so you can forget about it for the moment.

As for "for every x in the set of $D$, $P(x)$", this is an abbreviation for the statement "For every x, if $x\in D$ then $P(x)$". Thus the predicate that you are quantifying the free variables out of is "If $x\in D$ then $P(x)$".

This certainly has $x$ as a free variable, your question is why is $D$ not free too? Basically by stipultion, your professor is declaring that $D$ is a name for a set. Which set? Well that is important for saying whether the statement is true of false, but it is not important for deciding whether or not we have a predicate.

To contrast, you aren't asking why we are allowed to use $P(x)$ here without specifying exactly what it is, but it doesn't matter because we have declared that it is a predicate so everything works out. Similarly we declare that $D$ is a set and the collection of symbols "for every x in the set of $D$, $P(x)$" is a statement, independent of exactly what $D$ and $P(x)$ are.

Comment: So when exactly does a predicate become a statement? Is it when all variables are specified? Is there difference between specified and quantified?  I know that "for every x in the set of D, P(x)" is a statement about predicate P(x), but is x really quantified? I mean, x is said to be any element in set D, but we really do not know what D is, and thus we really haven't said what x is.

Comment: I don't know exactly the definitions you are using. But from the looks of what you have written above, a predicate has exactly one free variables, and a statement has none. So nothing can be both a predicate and a statement. However you can transform a predicate $P(x)$ into a statement by quantifying out the free variable $x$. Then it becomes bound and so what is left is a statement.

Comment: Predicate can have several variables from the definition.  Why isn't "for every x in the set of D, P(x)" a predicate in this manner since the set D is not quantified.

Comment: As I explained above, $D$ is not being treated as a variable here, it is being treated as a constant symbol.

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean. But how do I know when something is being treated as a constant or variable

Comment: By context or being told explicitly. Also (formal) variables tend to be denoted $x,y,z,w,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ or $X,Y,Z,W,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ where as constants tend to be denoted $c,d,c_1,c_2\ldots$ or $C,D,c_1,c_2,\ldots$.

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you, but i am still a little uncomfortable, maybe it will change as my class progress, will it?

Comment: I can't predict how you will feel in the future. However the important stuff in logic is what you do with the formal syntax you, so painstakingly, set up. Not the formal syntax itself.

Comment: OK，I just cannot find an good definition of these syntax. Do you know if there are any resource about the syntax of predicate? I cannot seem to find any online. Or maybe do you know any book that explain predicate? cannot find any book about predicate either. Only Predicate calculus...

Comment: You should look at your notes or ask your professor. There are a lot of minor variations, and I wouldn't want to tell you the wrong one.

Comment: OK。 Thanks. Is there a book that have all those kinds of information?

Comment: Plenty, again you should ask your professor for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The language of *first-order* logic is made of :

- sentential *connectives*
- *quantifiers*
- the *equality* symbol
- countable many (individual) *variables* : $x_1, x_2, \ldots$
- a set (possibly empty) of *constants*
- for each positive integer $n$, a set (possibly empty) of predicate variable : $P_1^n, \ldots$ .

Thus we can build a formula like :

> $\exists x_2 \forall x_1 \lnot P_1^2(x_1,x_2)$.

In order to give meaning to formulae, we need an *interpretation*, i.e. we have to choose a *domain* (usually not-empty) of objects : we will use it for interpreting the quantifiers, and a mapping of the constant symbols on "distinguished" objects of the domain and of the predicate symbols on *relations* (of suitable *arity*) on the domain.

*Note* : you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567598/interpreting-quantified-predicate-formulas) some more details.

---

We can consider some formalized language for mathematical theories :

*(i)* Language of set theory

> Equality: $=$; one binary predicate symbol : $\in$; a constant symbol : $\emptyset$.

Thus, using $\in$ in place of $P_1^2$ and introducing the abbreviations : $x \in y$ for $\in(x,y)$ and $x \notin y$ for $\lnot (x \in y)$, the above formula becomes :

> > $\exists x_2 \forall x_1 (x_1 \notin x_2)$

which is true in the *domain* of sets, because the domain includes the emptyset.

*(ii)* Language of elementary number theory

> Equality: $=$; one binary predicate symbol : $<$; a constant symbol : $0$.

Thus, using $<$ in place of $P_1^2$ and introducing the abbreviations : $x < y$ for $<(x,y)$ and $x \ge y$ for $\lnot (x < y)$, the above formula becomes :

> > $\exists x_2 \forall x_1 (x_1 \ge x_2)$

which is true in the *domain* of natural numbers, because the domain includes the number $0$.

---

The [bounded quantifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantifier) are not part of the "usual" language of first-order logic.

In the language of set theory

> there are two bounded quantifiers: $\forall x \in t$ and $\exists x \in t$. These quantifiers bind the set variable $x$ and contain a term $t$ (which may not mention $x$ but which may have other free variables).
>
> The semantics of these quantifiers is determined by the following rules:
>
> > $\exists x \in t\ (\varphi) \Leftrightarrow \exists x ( x \in  t \land \varphi)$
> >
> > $\forall x \in t\ (\varphi) \Leftrightarrow \forall x ( x \in t \rightarrow \varphi)$

Their use is clear; they "bound" or "restrict" the "range of application" of the quantifier to a specific set "named" by the *term* $t$; of course, $t$ must be a primitive or defined term of the lenguage, like $\omega$ for the set of natural numbers.

---

Consider now the expression :

> for every $x$ in the set of $D, P(x)$.

We can translate it as : $\forall x \in D (P(x))$.

The question is : what is the meaning of $D$, outside set theory ?

For a formula in first-order language we do not have to specify the domain of the interpretation of the formula: we choose a domain when we interpret it and the quantifiers and variables will receive a meaning through the interpretation.

Consider now the traditional example : "all men are mortal" and translate it in first-order logic in the usual way; we have :

$\forall x (Man(x) \rightarrow Mortal(x))$.

If we note that a subset of the domain of the interpretation is the denotation of a (unary) predicate symbol, we can use the set $Men$ for the intended meaning of the predicate $Man(x)$, and rewrite the above formula as :

$\forall x \in Men (Mortal(x))$.

But in first-order logic there are **no** variables ranging over the subsets of the domain; thus, $D$ cannot be a variable: it must be an "abbreviation" for some suitable unary predicate.

Thus, outside of set theory, the above formula is of little significance.

---

We can find bounded quantifiers used also in semi-formal mathematical contexts, like :

> $\forall x \in \mathbb R^+ \exists y (y^2=x)$.

In mathematical analysis, where the domain is the set of *real* numbers, can be useful to use this symbol to specify different subsets of $\mathbb R$, like in the example above, which is an abbreviation for :

> $\forall x (x \ge 0 \rightarrow \exists y (y^2=x))$.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are there so many different definitions of predicate??

I would be hard to go wrong just memorizing the definition given by your prof. It's enough to know that there are many subtle variations. At this point in your career, it would be a waste of time to try to determined which definition is the best. After working through several sample problems, it will become second nature.

> Also, my professor says that the following sentence is a statement, for every x in the set of D, P(x). Where P(x) is a predicate of variable x.
>
> We know that for a predicate to be a statement, we need to quantify all variables, however, in the above statement, we didn't know what set D is. I mean, If we do not know set D, why would the above statement be a statement?

You should clarify this with your prof, but D may just be his "well-defined domain of values." Or the *domain of quantification*. If he was writing this using a universal quantifier, he might write:

$\forall x: P(x)$

Some writers may be more explicit, especially if there is more than one domain of quantification under consideration as often happens in mathematics:

$\forall x\in D: P(x)$

Both can be thought of as *statements.* Opinions may vary, but it is a very minor point.

Answer (score 0):

As we know **any indicative sentence that is True or False but not both ,is a statement** , so in this case $D$ is a set and we don't know about its content and we say for every $x$ in the set of $D$, $P(x)$ and this point that "we didn't know what set $D$ is" may be cause that our statement be False or maybe be True anyway it's is not against out define !

Comment: But then why x has to be quantified, i mean, if set D does not has to be specified, why x has to. We said for every x but we never said for every set D.

Comment: in this case $x$ is a variable and when we say $x$ in D we accepted $x$ is one of its subset !

Comment: What do you mean by "it's is not against out define !"

Comment: i mean its(the problem that you think) not against this `any indicative sentence that is True or False but not both ,is a statement `

Comment: But if you say even if we don't know what set D is, it is a statement. What if we don't know what x is? In this case, it is no longer a statement.  I feel like if you say set D doesn't matter, why does x matter?

Comment: Ok ... as i say you have a True Reasoning but in question like this before all of this you must think about D and x that those are a set and subset that surely x is in D ! if we dont know x is in D or not it was actually false !